# iPhone 4 with updated iOS 7 not synching some contacts

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone, contacts, ios

Since updating to iOS 7 on my iPhone 4, the home address of some of Outlook contacts do not sync to the phone.  Some contacts will show home and work, and some will not show any address on the iPhone. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have my gmail set up as an exchange account on my iphone. Since the update to ios 7, home addresses are not showing up in my contacts - only work addresses are. But they are still there when I go into gmail contacts.
Any advice?

Comment: Hmm - it's your call if you want to edit this extra detail into the question at hand or ask a separate one. It's not an answer, so let's move it to the comments section for now.

Answer (score 1):

We saw the same issue on my wife's iPhone 4 and were able to get around the issue by adding a quick new dummy address. Suddenly the home address displayed for the person. Certainly not easy to do for all your contacts, but it is a quick work around if you know you had someone's address and want to get it without going to your computer.

I do not have the same issue on my iPhone 5. But I cannot confirm that the issue is the phone though. I rather suspect the issue is more related to the exchange servers used by our different employers.

Comment: If you have a ton of contacts to edit using the workaround, it would be easier to use a PC and add the dummy address to the iPhone contacts from there by editing them with this: http://www.copytrans.net/support/edit-iphone-contacts-pc/